# How to Fetch Current location of Taken Picture from Camera in Android

Tags: android, image, location, photos

I am trying to fetch location of captured picture from camera. When I tried Exif interface but still return null value from photos.Please somebody help...

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        // Let's read picked image data - its URI
        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
        // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        img1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));


        ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(img1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String lat = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE;
            String lat_data = exif.getAttribute(lat);
            Log.e("MYDATA", lat_data);
            cursor.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: share your code what you have tried

Comment: verify your file really has location data, most of the time android devices has the feature disable by default in camera app.

Comment: Actually i enable geotaging in android device.

Comment: exif.getLatLong(latLong); worked for me but is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Content resolver to build ExifInterface with inputStream

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        final Uri originalUri = intent.getData();

        try {
            final InputStream inputStream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(originalUri);
            final android.support.media.ExifInterface exif = new android.support.media.ExifInterface(inputStream);
            final double[] latLong = exif.getLatLong();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Image selected at position: " + latLong[0] + " : " + latLong[1]);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Error when getting location from image", e);
        }
    }
```

Support lib import

```
compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:x.x.x'
```

Comment: check documentation api, method has changed in different version of api. Use support version import android.support.media.ExifInterface;

Comment: ExifInterface exif = null;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(img1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String lat = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE;
            String lat_data = exif.getAttribute(lat);
            Log.e("MYDATA", lat_data);
            String log = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE;
            String log_data = exif.getAttribute(log);
            Log.e("MYDATA1", log_data);                               Thanks i getting solution using this code

Comment: Thanks to all for replaying